# One Level nesting in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table as

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| category_id | name                 | parent_category_id |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|           1 | Pizzas               |               NULL |
|           2 | Cheese Pizzas        |                  1 |
|           3 | Spicy Pizzas         |                  1 |
|           4 | Shakes               |               NULL |
|           5 | Milk Shakes          |                  4 |
```

I have only single level nesting and its going to be the same

I wish to retrieve the rows like

```
Pizza
   Cheese Pizzas
   Spicy Pizzas
Shakes
   Milk Shakes
```

Is there something like "Trees" In MySQL as in Oracle, I did read the article http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Changing the table structure seems more feasible when there is dynamic levels of nesting, for my case its just going to be 1 throughout

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a self-join and do something like:

```
SELECT   parent.category_id, parent.name AS parent, child.name AS child
FROM     my_table parent JOIN my_table child
      ON parent.parent_category_id IS NULL
     AND child.parent_category_id = parent.category_id
ORDER BY parent.category_id, child.category_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8bf7/1/0).

Or even group the results, if so desired:

```
SELECT   parent.name, GROUP_CONCAT(child.name ORDER BY child.category_id)
FROM     my_table parent JOIN my_table child
      ON parent.parent_category_id IS NULL
     AND child.parent_category_id = parent.category_id
GROUP BY parent.category_id
ORDER BY parent.category_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8bf7/2/0).

Comment: Currently using the first query, but need to get its child below the its parent

Comment: @Akash: Do that within your application, by testing for changes in `parent.category_id`.

Comment: Isn't this possible via a Query in Mysql?

Comment: @Akash: I'm not sure I understand the question.  How do you expect the resultset to look?

Comment: The retrieved resultset from the DB, should have a row containing the parent first and then on the next lines (with some spaces) its subsequent child's, same as shown in the question

Comment: @Akash: You could use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to achieve something like [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b134/1/0).